# Why can't I have a class which contains a list of objects of the same class?

Tags: python, class, oop, object

I have the following class:

```
class Group(object):
    _name = ''
    _link = ''
    _collection = []
```

And I have the following function:

```
def getSubGroups(url, groups):
    group = groups[0]
    #sleep(15)
    html = requests.get(url+group.getLink())
    content = BeautifulSoup(html.text, "lxml")
    subGroup = None
    #Retrieving groups and people listed above these groups
    for div in content.find_all('div', {"class":["size14", "person-box"]}):
      #Group
      if "size14" in div.attrs['class']:
        if subGroup != None:
          #Adding a subgroup to its repective subgroup
          group.addCollection(subGroup)
          print 'NFL = ', group.getName()
          print '2014...', subGroup.getName()
          print 'List of groups', group.getCollection()
          print 'List of persons', subGroup.getCollection()
          break
        subGroup = Group()
        subGroup.setLink(div.a['href'])
        subGroup.setName(div.text)
      #Person
      if "person-box" in div.attrs['class']:
        divPerson = div.find('div', 'name')
        person = Person()
        person.setName(divPerson.text)
        person.setLink(divPerson.a['href'])
        #Adding a person to its repective group
        subGroup.addCollection(person)
    return group
```

That print gives me the following output:

```
NFL =  NFL Players 
2014... 2014 NFL Draft Picks and Rookies
List of groups [<Person.Person object at 0x7fd79a4bff50>, <Person.Person object at
0x7fd79a4bff90>, ..., <Group.Group object at 0x7fd79a4bff10>]
List of persons [<Person.Person object at 0x7fd79a4bff50>, <Person.Person object at
0x7fd79a4bff90>, ..., <Person.Person object at 0x7fd79a454990>,
<Group.Group object at 0x7fd79a4bff10>]
```

As those who paid attention can see, I am running a test and I was expecting to have => List of groups `[<Group.Group object at 0x7ff54bb86350>]`, but instead it added all of the person objects there as well.

Just to test my sanity, I created another class named Subgroup and now it works fine for me. But still, in Java or C++ I could do that, I suppose. Why can't I with python? I didn't want to have to create another class that is exactly the same!

Comment: What is `group`?  What is `addCollection`?  Your code doesn't show anything that actually adds things to `_collection`.

Comment: BreenBarn, sorry for not posting the methods, I am new here, but bear in mind that addCollection is a method of the class as the following:

def addCollection(self, data):
      self._collection.append(data)

Comment: `subGroup.addCollection(person)` – You never change which group `subGroup` references, so of course you end up adding everything to it. Also: Don’t write getter/setter method in Python.

Comment: sorry poke, I didn't really get what you meant.  The problem here is that group is getting person, but group was only supposed to have subgrop and then subgroup to have person.

Comment: BTW, What is wrong with getters/setters in Python?

Comment: Accessors in other languages are primarily to allow access to private variables (sometimes to control how they're used). Python doesn't have encapsulation (everything is public), so adding a getter for it's own sake doesn't buy you anything. Don't worry, if you're new to python from Javaland, it may take a while to realize a lot of the patterns that you're used to don't make sense in python. Welcome, it's better here.

Comment: Seth, thank you for your explanation, but I don't think I will get rid of my getters and setters, not because of encapsulation but because they are very useful for log files and updating other system information. But thank you for your attention anyway, it was a good point, tho.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is likely your issue.

```
class Group(object):
    _name = ''       #  <--- variables defined here belong
    _link = ''       #  <--- to the class itself, not to 
    _collection = [] #  <--- class instances.
```

When you define variables directly under a class like that, they are actually class variables (something like static variables in Java or C++).

When you print your collections, notice that the hex numbers are the same in both print lines. That's likely because `group._collection` and `subGroup._collection` refer to the same list (`Group._collection`, the list defined at the class level). That's why you see `Person` and `Group` in the list - your subgroup is adding `Person` objects to the list, and your group is adding `Group` objects.

In python, instance variables are defined inside the `__init__` function (similar to a constructor in Java/C++).

I suspect you want to do something like this:

```
class Group(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self._name = ''        # <--- variables defined here
        self._link = ''        # <--- belong to the instance only
        self._collection = []
```

Then, each time you say `Group()`, you'll be creating a new `Group` object that has it's own list called `_collection`.

Comment: Thank you, I didn`t know about this regarding python. I knew what was the problem behind the screen, (regarding the hex numbers and so on) but I really didn`t know a way to solve it. Now it works just fine. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Sure thing. Incidentally the hex numbers are often the actual memory address where a thing is located. So if they're the same, then it's the same object.